# PaginatedDatatable: BoxConstraints forces an infinite width

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [PaginatedDataTable].

class MyDataSource extends DataTableSource {
  @override
  int get rowCount => 3;

  @override
  DataRow? getRow(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return const DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
            DataCell(Text('19')),
            DataCell(Text('Student')),
          ],
        );
      case 1:
        return const DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Janine')),
            DataCell(Text('43')),
            DataCell(Text('Professor')),
          ],
        );
      case 2:
        return const DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('William')),
            DataCell(Text('27')),
            DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
          ],
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}

final DataTableSource dataSource = MyDataSource();

void main() => runApp(const DataTableExampleApp());

class DataTableExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DataTableExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: DataTableExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DataTableExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const DataTableExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              PaginatedDataTable(
                columns: const <DataColumn>[
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text('Name'),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text('Age'),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text('Role'),
                  ),
                ],
                source: dataSource,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
FlutterError (BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
These invalid constraints were provided to _RenderScrollSemantics's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
  ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:52:11)
The offending constraints were:
  BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=Infinity))
```

The PaginatedDataTable should have its natural size. Hard-coded width/height will not work in our real app.

The widget tree above is the minimized version of our real code to reproduce the error.

which widget enforce BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=Infinity))? The Wrap and Column enforce 0.0<=w<=Infinity and 0.0<=h<=Infinity, not w=infinity.

Comment: and what's the reason of using `Wrap` and `Column` widgets with just one child?

Comment: This is minimized version of our real app code to reproduce the error.

Comment: "which widget enforce .. " `Wrap` does it, if you remove `direction` you will see that `BoxConstraints` will change

Comment: Wrap forces: 0.0<=w<=Infinity, but the error says: w=Infinity. For 0.0<=w<=Infinity constraint (same as children of Row), the PaginatedDataTable should figure out its own size. right?

Comment: It tries to fill the available width which is infinity in your case, try just for test to wrap `PaginatedDataTable` with `ConstrainedBox` with `maxWidth: 320` for example and you will see that table will fill 320 pixels in horizontal axis

Comment: or even better wrap it with `ConstraintsTransformBox` and return `constraints.copyWith(maxWidth: 320)` from its `constraintsTransform` callback

Comment: Hard-coded width will fix the error, but will not work well for dynamic dataTable that can have any number of columns. Wondering why the table tries to expand instead of calculating its own natural size from content. Thanks.

Comment: if you need such dynamic grid then use [TableView](https://pub.dev/documentation/two_dimensional_scrollables/latest/table_view/TableView-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Wrap` and `Column` and you will end up with the table that fills all the available space.

```
class DataTableExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const DataTableExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PaginatedDataTable(
                columns: const <DataColumn>[
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text('Name'),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text('Age'),
                  ),
                  DataColumn(
                    label: Text('Role'),
                  ),
                ],
                source: dataSource,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is minimized version of our real app code to reproduce the error.